# Drupal 7 forms don't work after migration. Form fields become empty after submitting

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I made a full migration of the Drupal site (both code and DB).

At first sight site works fine.  All the pages and page content are fully available.

But all the POST forms don't work. I tried to put test messages to form hooks. Form generation works fine, but both validation and send hooks were not even called.

Moreover, all standard forms (for example Sign Up Form) don't work too.

Just after submitting form fields become empty without any errors or warnings.

Looks like all the differences between environments are:

1. PHP version. (from PHP 5.4 to PHP 5.5)
2. Different path on server
3. Another domain name (dev/staging)

But, I'm not sure. I might missed something else.

Does anybody have any ideas what could cause this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the reason of the problem was very simple and so confusing at the same time.

It's not a Drupal-related issue, it's quite strange behavior of Apache Web Server.

The mod_rewrite was disabled in Apache configuration (shame on me). But, despite this fact, Apache was managing all redirects, thus pages were returning correct content but with 404 response code! It caused empty POSTs and, as result, broken forms.

I still can't realize why Apache behaves this way... 
Anyhow,the problem was solved.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem. Thank you so much for posting this. It's so weird that pages still loaded properly with the "pretty" URLs without `mod_rewrite` enabled. Really threw me off.

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been killing me, and I lost several days because I was blaming it on PHP 7.2, not Apache.